# Lego style split screen camera in godot

Tags: godot

I want to have [lego style splitscreen camera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipr9U8OTgxU) with seamless transitions.

Anyone has any experience creating something like this? I thought of creating one normal camera and then another camera for second player that by default wouldn't be visible. Then, when i would want to show it, i would draw a triangle to split the screen and set it texture as camera #2 view.

I found [this Unity implementation](https://github.com/Swegrock/Dynamic-Splitscreen) but i couldn't implement it in Godot. I've managed to create second viewport with it's own camera, but for some reason the view of the second camera is not showing anything. I'm thinking that the problem is that the world of the second viewport is different than the main viewport.

Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/helenaW/greatRepoForAwesomeGame/tree/ff1ac1e883e418a04a7083a3b07fcffafc20ff8d).

Answer (score 4):

I just setup a toy project to test this out and it turned out to be simpler than expected.

Here is an overview of the process and then code examples will follow.

1. Add one main camera
2. And a secondary camera with tree: Control > Viewport > Camera
3. Draw the shape of the split screen with Control using the draw_* api
4. Add a shader to Control that takes a texture and draws it at SCREEN_UV
5. Get the viewport texture from Viewport
6. Pass the viewport texture to the Control shader every frame.
7. Animate the split by animating and redrawing the Control shape.

I'm not sure how to do the border.

To make the split join you'll probably have to shift the Control shape by the thickness of border and then shrink that border as the cameras go towards each other. Use that distance between the players to calculate the border width.

The split border is also at an angle between the two players so when animating the shape you'll want to use that angle. This will make the joining of the viewport look smoother.

Control code:

```
extends Control

func _draw():
    # in this case animate tl and bml to get the 
    # rotating split like effect in the lego game
    var tl = Vector2()
    var tr = rect_size
    tr.y = 0
    var br = rect_size
    var bml = rect_size
    bml.x /= 2.0
    draw_polygon([tl, tr, br, bml, tl], [Color(), Color(), Color(), Color(), Color()], [])

func _process(d):
    material.set_shader_param('viewport', $Viewport.get_texture())
```

Shader Code:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform sampler2D viewport;

void fragment(){
    COLOR=texture(viewport, SCREEN_UV);
}
```

I hope this helps get you started!

Answer (score 1):

It is a complex effect with many parts so be warned.

I found that the easiest way is to create a separate scene with your viewports and cameras which will be your main scene and then add your game scene under it like this:

```
Spatial
    Viewport1
        Camera1
    Viewport2
        Camera2
    GameScene
```

You should then be able to make a `ColorRect` with a shader material and send in the textures from each viewport:

```
shader_type canvas_item;
render_mode unshaded, cull_disabled;

uniform sampler2D viewport1;
uniform sampler2D viewport2;

void fragment() {
    vec3 view1 = texture(viewport1, UV).rgb;
    vec3 view2 = texture(viewport2, UV).rgb;

    vec3 col = vec3(0);

    // mix them in a satisfying way depending on distance and angle between cameras
    // float mixVal = <your formula here>
    // col = mix(view1, view2, mixVal)

    COLOR = vec4(col, 0.0); // this may not work in Godot shaders
}
```

This is a great guide to get you started:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/viewports/using_viewport_as_texture.html